# How can a UIView get a callback when it is added to its superview?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

## Problem

I have subclassed a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). After an object of this subclass is added to its superview, it needs to autonomously run some code. How can I hook on to this event to run my code?

## Why I Need It

The background of the selected segmented of a [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) has been notoriously hard to style. The best solution I could find is doing this hack:

```
#import "SegmentedControlStyled.h"

@implementation SegmentedControlStyled

- (void) updateStyle
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++) {
        if ([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected]) {
            [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        if ([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(isSelected)] && ![[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected]) {
            [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0]];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

This `updateStyle` function needs to be called in two places. Obviously, the first is whenever the a user taps a different segment. I can do this autonomously by overriding my `SegmentedControlStyled`'s `addTarget` function and hooking on to the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event. The second place `updateStyle` needs to be called is *after* a `SegmentedControlStyled` is added to its superview. You may ask, "why do you call it after and not somewhere like `init`?". Well, from my observations, calling it before it is attached to the view hiearchy has no effect. Therefore, one needs to write their code like this:

```
SegmentedControlStyled* seg = [[SegmentedControlStyled alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];
[self.view addSubview:seg];
[seg updateStyle];
```

The last line is ugly, because the co-worker who uses my subclass has to understand why the view is broken and has to know when to call `updateStyle`. To uphold the Object Oriented principle of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), this detail should be moved into the class itself. If I had the ability to detect when a view has been added to its superview, I would be able to encapsulate the style hack within my subclass.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

override either of

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow
```

as appropriate?

Comment: I ended up using `willMoveToSuperview`. Inside that function, I did `[self performSelector:@selector(updateStyle) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];`. Calling it immediately could not restyle the segmented control.

Comment: Even when using `- (void)didMoveToSuperview` instead? (ie once the parenting is done, note before it is)

Answer (score 0):

UISegmentedControl's selected state isn't hard to style.

You use the method `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` and use `UIControlStateSelected` as the argument for named parameter `forState:`.

Anything where you are accessing subviews of UIKit controls is a bad thing™. You shouldn't rely on internal implementation details.

Comment: How do I set it to a UIColor rather than UIImage?